# Filling empty white pixels with nearest coloured pixel

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gaussianblur

**Problem Statement:** I have an image obtained after plotting several points and coloured according to a certain parameter value. Since I need to perform contour detection, I need to actually form a "contour". Thus I need to colour the white pixel (especially in the top right of the image) inside the "contour" to have the same colour as the nearest coloured pixel. Alternatively, suggest a better morphological/blurring/smoothing technique.

[image]

**My attempt:**
[image]
As you can see that the corrected components appear jagged (Used erosion and blur selectively to the right half of the image). Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: unfortunately your pictures appear to be resampled, so there is no clear color/background separation. you ought to work from the points themselves, not a picture of these points. scipy has *interpolation* functions that can turn a bunch of "colored" points into a dense approximation

Comment: take a look https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata